# Weird behaviour tableview scrolling

Tags: ios, ipad, scroll, scrollbar, uitableview

I'm developing an iPad App on xcode 4.6.1 for iOs 6.1.

So I have a tableview I push into the navigation stack. That table has lots of cells outside of sight.  When I scroll down, after lifting the finger, it scrolls automatically to top, something I don't want.  (The scroll bar also doesn't show up)

Now the weird part. When I present a popover from a barbutton on that same view and dismiss it, scrolling works as expected. This let me think it has something to do with will/didappear methods, but I tried to overwrite them with no super, or don't overwrite them, doesn't help.

I also tried disabling paging (IB and programmatically) with no success and even reset the derived data from xcode and deleted the app in the simulator (I had some storyboard "freezing" (bug?) sometime)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this by calling `[self.tableview reloadData]` in `viewDidAppear`.
No idea what i'm doing wrong.